# PHP Login Form (no sql) - Validated against text file records - Not validating

Tags: php, forms, validation, authentication

I'm working on a log in form that users a **text file** (users.txt) to validate username/password against. I cannot use MYSQL for this.

**The text file records are in this format:**

user one:user1@email.com:user1:password1

user two:user2@email.com:user2:password2

If it validate just the USERNAME only, then it successfully checks the user: if `($currUser == $userUsername) {$valid = true; break;}`**BUT** if I then try to validate both username and password I get the wrong result.`($currUser == $userUsername && $currPass == $userPass) {$valid = true; break;}` Results in ***"Invalid username or password"***

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? When I echo the username and passwords they are a match!!!

**SCRIPT:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $form_is_submitted = true;

   //FORM PROCESSING
   if(isset($_POST['userName']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

      $currUser = $_POST['userName'];
      $currPass = $_POST['password'];
      $valid = false;//flag
      while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
          $userRow = fgets($fileHandle);
          $userDetails = explode(':', $userRow);
          if (!isset($userDetails[2])) {
              $userDetails[2] = null;
          }
          if (!isset($userDetails[3])) {

              $userDetails[3] = null;
          }
          $userUsername = $userDetails[2];
          $userPass = $userDetails[3];
          if ($currUser == $userUsername /*&& $currPass == $userPass*/) {
              $valid = true;
              //break;
          }
      }    
      if ($valid) {
         echo "<br> $userUsername logged in sucessfully<br>";
      } else {
         echo "<br>Invalid user name or password<br>";
         //FOR DEGUGGING ONLY!
         echo $currUser . $userUsername;
         echo $currPass . $userPass;
         echo $_POST['password'];
         echo $_POST['userName'];

      }
  } else {    
     $errors_detected = true;
     $errors['not set'] = "Please enter username and password";
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you got some special character (line feed or whatever) in the password string. Have you tried using `trim()` on `$userPass`?

Comment: @Typoheads great shout! 8 hours messing around with this and all that was needed was trim()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `fgets()` function returns a line INCLUDING the linefeed `\n` (and the carriage return `\r` if its there). that means you have to remove those.

just change this:

```
$userPass = $userDetails[3];
```

to this:

```
$userPass = trim($userDetails[3]);
```

and it should work